# Errors with a phpMyAdmin install on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, php, phpmyadmin

Well, I was trying to install phpMyAdmin on CentOS 7 (64bit) and this happens.

Here is a [Pastebin of the output from `yum install phpmyadmin`](http://pastebin.com/D40zyyzW) because can’t get code thing to work.

```
[root@ftb ~]# yum install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos.dfw.quadranet.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: centos.host-engine.com
 * updates: centos.arvixe.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package phpMyAdmin.noarch 0:4.0.10.8-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-mcrypt >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-mbstring >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-gd >= 5.2.0 for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-xmlwriter for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-tcpdf for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-php-gettext for package: phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.8-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libt1.so.5()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-gd-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-php-gettext.noarch 0:1.0.11-3.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: php-bcmath for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
---> Package php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:6.2.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-sans-fonts for package: php-tcpdf-dejavu-sans-fonts-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: dejavu-fonts-common = 2.33-6.el7 for package: dejavu-sans-fonts-2.33-6.el7.noarch
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-5.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package php-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.4.16-23.el7_0.3 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
---> Package t1lib.x86_64 0:5.1.2-14.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package dejavu-fonts-common.noarch 0:2.33-6.el7 will be installed
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.3.3-3.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-tcpdf.noarch 0:6.2.4-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-tidy for package: php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.4-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-tidy
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.3.x86_64 (@updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-21.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-23.el7_0.1.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to install priorities:

```
yum install yum-priorities
```

Next edit your /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo:

```
nano /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

and add `priority=5` to remi repository. Warning: priority **MUST** be 10 on EPEL repository.

```
[remi-php56]
name=Remi's PHP 5.6 RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php56/$basearch/
mirrorlist=http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/7/php56/mirror
# NOTICE: common dependencies are in "remi-safe"
enabled=1
priority=5
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
```

then `yum update`
and `yum install php_mcrypt`
*normaly it works because it goes to the remy's repositiry to install php_mcrypt package.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are trying to install phpMyAdmin on CentOS 7. But looking at your command line output shows lines that contain stuff like this:

```
Package [package details removed for example].el6 will be installed
```

Look at the package extension of `.el6`; the “6” in there means that the packages being installed are from a CentOS 6 EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository. So I would recommend uninstalling what you have attempted to install already like this:

```
yum remove phpmyadmin
```

And then setup the correct EPEL repository for CentOS 7 like this; details from [this site](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-centos-7/):

```
rpm -iUvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-5.noarch.rpm
```

Now update your local list of packages:

```
yum -y update
```

And the attempt to install phpMyAdmin again like this:

```
yum -y install phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Tried what you said and I'm getting this:

@JakeGould
http://pastebin.com/K0ETE26U

Comment: Tried that, and got this:
http://pastebin.com/XeKWv1PM

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from the original question and follow up comments, you have an EL7 server, and you have added packages from:

- EPEL for EL6
- webtatic for EL7
- remi for EL7

You might as well just reinstall the OS at this point.  It is possible to recover, but the fact that you screwed things up this bad indicates that you don't have the necessary skill to unscrew things (no offense).  After you reinstall, decide if you want to use stock/EPEL (safe combo), webtatic, or remi.  Don't mix and match, especially between major OS versions.

Answer (score -1):

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 php-mcrypt
yum update
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what the first command does.  It is unwise to run a command without knowing what it does.  I personally know what it does but I don't have this problem.

Comment: The first command isn't valid.